# Zoom in and rotate animation in xml

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to make a image zoom in by using xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="6000"
       android:fromXScale="1dp"
       android:fromYScale="1dp"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:repeatCount="infinite"
       android:repeatMode="restart"
       android:toXScale="150dp"
       android:toYScale="150dp"/>
```

and rotate an image by using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

I cant use both scale and rotate in same xml. why?
how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29007592/1617737) is right. You have to add the `ordering` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="together">

    <scale
        android:duration="6000"
        android:fromXScale="1dp"
        android:fromYScale="1dp"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="150dp"
        android:toYScale="150dp"/>

    <rotate
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360"/>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `<set>` to combine it. The set is a container that holds other animation elements E.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale  
       android:duration="6000"
       android:fromXScale="1dp"
       android:fromYScale="1dp"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%" 
       android:toXScale="150dp"
       android:toYScale="150dp"/>

   <rotate 
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:toDegrees="360" />
  </set>
```

Comment: its not working. it comes by zooming and the image is displayed

Comment: try adding the android:ordering="together" to the set. How can I know they way you want to run the animation

Comment: the animation works only one time and the image looks shrunken.

Comment: But that isn't your initially issue, is it?

Comment: got it.  the animation was stoping and restarting. i used 'interpolar:linearInterploar'

Comment: Cool I am glad you figured it out